# Prove that the subset is a Borel set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the space of sequences of $0$s and $1$s. Define a metric on $X$ by setting $d(x,y)=2^{-\theta(x,y)}$ with $\theta(x,y)=\sup\{n:x_i=y_i \ \text{for all}\ 1\leq i\leq n \}$. Show that the set of sequences $x=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfying 
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}=\frac 1 3$$
>   is a Borel set.

I have no idea how to prove this. Could you give me some hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let fix large $N > 0$ and small $\varepsilon > 0$. Then define
$$S(N, \varepsilon) = \left\lbrace(x_n) \in X : n \ge N \implies \left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_n}{n} - \frac{1}{3}\right| < \varepsilon \right\rbrace.$$
Show that $S(N, \varepsilon)$ is open in $X$. Then the set you're interested in is
$$\bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} S(N, \varepsilon) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} S\left(N, \frac{1}{n}\right).$$

Comment: Isn't it better to look at $S'(N, \varepsilon) = \left\{(x_n) \in X : n \ge N \implies \left|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_n}{n} - \frac{1}{3}\right| \le \varepsilon \right\}$ and show that it is closed? It is not clear to me that your $S(N,\varepsilon)$ is open.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I agree with you.

Comment: (The correct complexity computation is that $S (N,\epsilon) $ is $G_\delta $. This still shows that the set in question is Borel, but suggests erroneously that it is of higher Borel complexity than it really is.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that simplifies the proof by invoking basic facts about measurable functions. For any n $\{x \in X:x_n=0\}=\{x:d(x,0) \leq 2^{-n}\}$ so the map $x \to x_n$ is measurable for each n. It follows that $ x \to \frac {\sum x_i} n$ is also measurable for each n. The limit superior and the limit  inferior of this sequence are measurable and the given is the one where these two are both equal to $\frac 1 3$.

Comment: I think it should be $\{x \in X:x_n=0\}\supseteq \{x:d(x,0) \leq 2^{-n}\}$.

Comment: It should also be $d(x,0^\omega)$ instead of $d(x,0)$.

Comment: Yes, I used 0 to denote the sequence $\{0,0,...\}$

Comment: Yes, I made a small mistake in showing that $x \to x_n$ is measurable. This map continuous because $d(x,y)<2^{-n}$ implies $x_n =y_n$. Continuous functions are measurable.